# jekyll don't set site.safe to true when production environment

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I use jekyllbootstrap to generate my website.

But i find the jekyll didn't set the site.safe to true. so my google analytics don't show on production environment.

I test site.safe site.JB.analytics.provider and page.JB.analytics, finally find the reason is the site.safe is still false when on github pages.

Do anyone know what's the reason?

Now the only solution is manually set site.safe to true when in local environment and push to github. but the analytics may get unreal data, because I usually modify my theme and preview locally.

What should i do? help me. thx everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site.safe` is one of the global options that github runs jekyll with.
You can see the options if you run the following:

```
jekyll help

--safe
    Safe mode (defaults to false)
```

You will find more about that issue here: https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/issues/84